gulp why I get the Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format?
I am using gulp to simply clone a src folder (jpeg images only).
I used the official documentation -> (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scale-images)
When I enter gulp in my terminal to run my script I get the following lines shown in terminal:
PS D:\__HOME\09_Kunde\#24000\Anwendercode> gulp
[19:14:48] Using gulpfile D:\__HOME\09_Kunde\#24000\Anwendercode\gulpfile.js
[19:14:48] Starting 'default'...
[19:14:48] 'default' errored after 44 ms
[19:14:48] Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format

Here are my devDependencies for version info:
  "devDependencies": {
    "flat-map": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-scale-images": "^3.0.3"   }

Here is my JS-Code:


const gulp = require('gulp')
const flatMap = require('flat-map').default
const scaleImages = require('gulp-scale-images')

function defaultTask(cb) {
    const twoVariantsPerFile = (file, cb) => {
        const jpegFile = file.clone()
        jpegFile.scale = {maxWidth: 150, format: 'jpeg'}
        const jpegFile2 = file.clone()
        jpegFile2.scale = {maxWidth: 300, format: 'jpeg'}
        const jpegFile3 = file.clone()
        jpegFile3.scale = {maxWidth: 600, format: 'jpeg'}
        const jpegFile4 = file.clone()
        jpegFile4.scale = {maxWidth: 900, format: 'jpeg'}
        const jpegFile5 = file.clone()
        jpegFile5.scale = {maxWidth: 1200, format: 'jpeg'}
        
        const webpFile = file.clone()
        webpFile.scale = {maxWidth: 150, format: 'webp'}
        const webpFile2 = file.clone()
        webpFile2.scale = {maxWidth: 300, format: 'webp'}
        const webpFile3 = file.clone()
        webpFile3.scale = {maxWidth: 600, format: 'webp'}
        const webpFile4 = file.clone()
        webpFile4.scale = {maxWidth: 900, format: 'webp'}
        const webpFile5 = file.clone()
        webpFile5.scale = {maxWidth: 1200, format: 'webp'}
       
        cb(null, [
            jpegFile, 
            jpegFile2, 
            jpegFile3, 
            jpegFile4, 
            jpegFile5, 
            webpFile,
            webpFile2, 
            webpFile3, 
            webpFile4, 
            webpFile5])
    }
     
    return gulp.src('images/**/*.{jpeg,jpg}')
        .pipe(flatMap(twoVariantsPerFile))
        .pipe(scaleImages())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/images"))
}

exports.default = defaultTask



Screenshot of my code and my error message
I tried different paths, and I googled. I did not find a solution.
The folder only holds .jpg files. Why do I get the error message?
Is there a possibility to console.log the input buffer?
Is there a possibility that my code runs to fast and the images are not loaded yet?
Should I add a await function? If yes how?
Any help is appreciated - Thank you in advance

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78450106/836330

I tried it. Sadly it is not working, but I get a new error:
[02:38:11] Using gulpfile D:__HOME\09_Kunde#24000\Anwendercode\gulpfile.js
[02:38:11] Starting 'default'...
[02:38:12] 'default' errored after 346 ms
[02:38:12] Error in plugin "gulp-scale-images"
Message:
file.scale must be an object
Details:
file: [object Object]

If you put a breakpoint on jpegFile.scale, is jpeg defined?

jpeg should be defined inside gulp script, right? I went threw it with the debugger.. Howeever there is a real big script behind it. when into the .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/images")) part the error occurs.
I went back to an older version and now it is working..
Thank you for your time. You are a giant.
However - would be nice to get it running with the newest release..
